# Undefined method error for a variable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i am developing an application where a user can post an issue and can comment on it.

the code for the issues/show.html.erb is

```
<h1><%=@issue.title%></h1><br />
<h3><%=@issue.content%></h3><br />



<%= link_to "Edit ", :controller => 'issues', :action => 'edit', :id => @issue.id %>



<h2>Comments</h2>

<%= render @issue.comments %>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<%= simple_form_for [@issue, Comment.new] do |f| %>
<%= f.label :content %><br />
<%= f.input :content %>
<%= f.submit "comment"%>
<%end%>
```

and the code for the comment controller is

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController


def create 
    @issue = Issue.find(params[:issue_id])
    @comment = @issue.comments.create(comment_params)

    if @comment.save
        redirect_to :controller => 'issues', :action => 'show'
    else 
        render 'new'
    end
end 





private
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:content)

    end


end
```

and the code for the comments partial is

```
<%= @comment.content%>
```

On running this code, rails is throwing an error - undefined method content, whereas content is the name of a column in my application
PLease help

Comment: can you post your `params` too?

Comment: I didn't get you. Which params ??

Comment: `params` are sent when you submit the form, what is you action which is calling that partial, post that method and view from where your are calling that `partial`, it will help us to help you

Comment: @Sontya
`<h1><%=@issue.title%></h1><br />
<h3><%=@issue.content%></h3><br />



<%= link_to "Edit ", :controller => 'issues', :action => 'edit', :id => @issue.id %>



<h2>Comments</h2>

<%= render @issue.comments %>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<%= simple_form_for [@issue, Comment.new] do |f| %>
<%= f.label :content %><br />
<%= f.input :content %>
<%= f.submit "comment"%>
<%end%>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments partial shouldn't be trying to use `@comment` it should be using just `comment` which the Rails `render` method will set to each comment object in `@issue.comments` as it iterates over the partial.

[See the excellent guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) on this feature for more information.